# Quarkus - Reactive file download

Tags: http, kotlin, download, reactive, quarkus

Using [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/), can somebody give an example on how the server and client side code using a reactive API to download a file over http looks?

So far I tried to return a Flux of nio ByteBuffers but it seems not to be supported:

```
@RegisterRestClient(baseUri = "http://some-page.com")
interface SomeService {

    // same interface for client and server
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/somePath")
    fun downloadFile(): reactor.core.publisher.Flux<java.nio.ByteBuffer>
}
```

Trying to return a Flux on the server-side results in the following exception:

```
ERROR: RESTEASY002005: Failed executing GET /somePath
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.FlowAsFlux of media type: application/octet-stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$3(ServerResponseWriter.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:403)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:251)
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/tree/master/reactive-file-download) is an example how to start reactive file download with smallrye mutiny. Main function is getFile

```
@GET
@Path("/f/{fileName}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Uni<Response> getFile(@PathParam String fileName) {
    File nf = new File(fileName);
    log.info("file:" + nf.exists());
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) nf);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + nf);
    Uni<Response> re = Uni.createFrom().item(response.build());
    return re;
}
```

You can test in your local with `mvn quarkus:dev` and go to this url to see what files are there http://localhost:8080/hello/list/test and after that you can call this url to start download http://localhost:8080/hello/f/reactive-file-download-dev.jar

I did not check about Flux(which looks like more spring then quarkus), feel free to share your thoughts. I am just learning and answering/sharing.

Comment: I've to admit that my question is nowadays no longer really sensible since reactor (Flux, Mono) has been deprecated inside of Quarkus in favor of mutiny (Multi, Uni). Thanks a lot for the example project!

Answer (score 1):

As of this [commit](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/16286), Quarkus has out-of-the-box support for `AsyncFile`. So, we can stream down a file by returning an `AsyncFile` instance.

For example, in a JAX-RS resource controller:

```java
// we need a Vertx instance for accessing filesystem
@Inject
Vertx vertx;
    
@GET
@Path("/file-data-1")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Uni<Response> streamDataFromFile1() 
{
     final OpenOptions openOptions = (new OpenOptions()).setCreate(false).setWrite(false);
     
        
     Uni<AsyncFile> uni1 = vertx.fileSystem()
        .open("/srv/texts/hello.txt", openOptions);
        
     return uni1.onItem()
        .transform(asyncFile -> Response.ok(asyncFile)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Hello.txt\"")
            .build());
}
```

Comment: Is this really how you'd do it or rather a low-level solution?